# ping fails but ssh succeeds

Tags: ssh, firewall, ping

I'm facing a situation where one app(using ssh) can connect from Machine A (Linux) to Machine B (windows), whereas Machine A cannot ping Machine B. Another app on Machine A which connects to Machine B (not using ssh) is also failing to connect

Can someone please tell me the reasons for the same? I suspect a firewall issue. Can this be due to a firewall? If so why does ssh still connect? Also how do I check for blocked ports and unblock the same?

Adding more information. Sorry for not providing the same before.
I'm using a Windows 7 operating system.
Running *netsh advfirewall firewall* returns `The service has not been started`.
It's on a company network so I'm sure there must be an external firewall which I would not be able to modify.

Comment: You doesnt say
1. Which OS you run
2. Type of firewall
3. List of firewall rules.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information, such as the operating systems that these machines are running. It's difficult to give specific answers to overly broad questions.

Comment: I'm sorry about being so generic. I'm new to this and will provide as much information as I can. I've added some info to the question. Please let me know if you require more information. I'm looking at understanding the behavior.

Comment: I've added the information to the question. Due to the external firewall, I'm not sure if it will answer your questions. If you do have any explanations for such behavior (ssh connects and ping fails), please provide some details on the same.

Comment: What OS is running on the machines? Is  there a firewall between the two machines ?

Comment: Machine A (The client) is a linux machine and machine B (The host) is a windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a firewall issue.

If your operating system is Linux:

Type `sudo iptables -L`.

If there is anything like

```
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             localhost
```

Run:

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT "n"
```

where `n` is the number of your iptable rule you found running `iptables -L`.

Comment: I've provided the details in the questions. Don't think I can do much with the firewall as it is for a network. Is there any way I can confirm the firewall issue from my side?? Also why would ssh succeed?? Would it be excluded from the same??

Comment: there are (arguably) 3 main protocols on the IPv4 stack. TCP, this is a reliable protocol and ensures delivery at the cost of speed, this is what SSH and most programs use. Pings are part of the ICMP protocol, its a completely different protocol to TCP and is treated differently. it requires that there be a program running on both sides to respond to ICMP requests, ICMP is for diagnostics and not data transmission, you can not send data with ICMP. UDP is the 3rd, it is fast but potentially unreliable, it is fairly similar to TCP but does not ensure delivery. many people block ICMP for security

Comment: @Silverfire: Thanks a lot for the reply. It makes things clearer to me. However I do have another app which is using another port (non-SSH). Even that app cannot connect. Could it be that everything is kinda blocked?? And that ssh has some special privileges?? Or the firewall rules allow the ssh port to be unblocked???

Comment: firewall from the sounds of it. Port 22 (ssh) is considered a pretty important port for most servers as it is the primary form of administration. Are you running through a proxy by any chance? ive seen sys-admins deny all traffic but web (through http proxy) and ssh (for admin reasons). check both the target and host firewalls.

Comment: @Silverfire: Thanks, that does make sense. Unfortunately, I don't think I have access to the firewalls, so won't be able to check the same. Is there anyway to find out whether a port is blocked?? From command line for windows??
Also, can you please frame you comments as an answer?? It clarifies most of my questions and I'll accept it

Comment: iptables v1.4.21: Invalid rule number `n'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Windows firewall isn't starting.  If you can't get the Windows firewall up and running (even if the firewall itself is disabled the service still needs to be running) then you won't be able to ping (or do much else on the network).

Comment: I guess my Windows firewall is disabled. But that should allow me to perform all activities on the network right?? I do have an external firewall whose configuration I don't have access to.

Comment: Nope, when the Windows firewall isn't working Windows defaults no basically nothing working on the network.  This is different from the old way in Windows XP or Vista when it defaulted to allowing everything.