# SSH works, ping and https get no response

Tags: ssh, http, ping, ubuntu-18.04

**Background:**
I'm trying to configure an ubuntu server to run a node.js application with https.
I previously had everything working fine with http (configured a year ago), and I wanted to open the firewall for :443 and redirect it to :8443:

```
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

When trying out my app, it turned out the https request didn't register with the app (nothing in the app-logs, and browser never gets a response to the request). When I ping the server, I also don't get a response (it doesn't even time out). My cloud provider dashboard also states that it can't ping the server, and the cloud provider firewall config also says 443 is allowed for all tcp.
... But, I can still ssh onto the server without an issue.

**Question**
How can I troubleshoot this? As far as I can tell

- :443 is allowed on the firewall
- :443 redirects to :8443
- node is listening to :8443

```
    sudo ufw status
    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
    80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
    443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


    sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 9477 packets, 1121K bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1413K   59M REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 8443

    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6826 packets, 410K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 74 packets, 6925 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 74 packets, 6925 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


    sudo netstat -ntlp
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      108911/systemd-reso 
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112287/sshd         
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1022            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      125785/sshd         
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      112287/sshd         
    tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      125414/node         
    tcp6       0      0 :::1022                 :::*                    LISTEN      125785/sshd


sudo iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 120 packets, 30108 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
 381K   34M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
  998 94467 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
 8163 1107K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  54M   15G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2892K  172M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5873 packets, 874K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-logging-deny (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-not-local (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Please add the result of "iptables -L -nv" command. ICMP may be blocked. You should add logs when a packet is dropped : it will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Added the command result. 
How do I "add logs when a packet is dropped"? Are these firewall logs?
I'm checking this out for ICMP https://askubuntu.com/questions/6995/how-to-enable-ufw-firewall-to-allow-icmp-response

Comment: ICMP seems enabled. `-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Similar questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/311612/ping-fails-but-ssh-succeeds
https://serverfault.com/questions/392704/ssh-connection-refused-with-out-iptables-rulles?rq=1

Comment: I would change the REDIRECT inside your PREROUTING into DNAT: https://serverfault.com/questions/179200/difference-beetween-dnat-and-redirect-in-iptables

Answer (score 0):

Restart ufw.

```
sudo systemctl restart ufw
```

Your iptables output shows that most of the rules added by ufw are missing. This is caused by manually flushing the tables (e.g. `sudo iptables -F`) while ufw is still running, something that will of course also flush ufw's rules and cause lots of breakage, but random Internet tutorials will tell you to do.